# In SharePoint,how to know whether a List is a KPI List?

Tags: sharepoint

For example,I want to do something like this:

```
 foreach(SPList list in web1.Lists )
    {
        if(current list is KPI List)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(list.Title);
        }
    }
```

So if the list is KPI List,I will add it to a DropDownList.
How can I solve it?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you check the ContentTypes property of SPList you should be able to figure that out.

Comment: The ContentTypes of KPI List and other Lists are "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection",but thanks to your idea,I found that the DefaultView property can figure it out.

Comment: Yes you will get the collection but you can loop through and check whether KPI content type having known Id is applied or not.